# Power BI Desktop direct Redshift connection with tenant, client and secret params

Tags: powerbi, amazon-redshift, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to configure a direct connect from Power BI desktop to AWS Redshift, but my connection is not just user and password I need to be able to input the following variables for the connection to be accepted by the Redshift cluster:

- client_id=x;
- client_secret=x;
- idp_tenant=x;
- ClusterID=x;
- DbGroups=x;
- Region=x;
- plugin_name=AzureAD
- IAMAuth=true

Ususally in a jdbc or odb connection I would be able to input that as part of the url, but I have not been able to find where to input this at the PBI desktop connection dialog

[image]

[image]

Has anyone been successful on configuring a connection to Redshift using parameters?

I have tried to input the params as part of the server details using the format:

```
server:port;param=value;param2=value;
```

and to place the variables at the advance options provider name and it does not work

I'm able to set an odbc connection but it is not ideal as it is much more slower

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Power BI graphical interface for connecting to databases is designed for simplicity and does not expose an interface for custom connection string parameters directly.

As a workaround, and since you mentioned that you're able to set up an ODBC connection even if it is slow you can adjust the fetch size, disable unnecessary logging, or enable compression if supported by the AWS Redshift ODBC driver.

Or you may need to use third-party tools or customized connectors for that (like CData Connectors for Power BI and Redshift or Devart ODBC Drivers for example)